# Add some points to the graph manually and update indexes using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have an algorithm to find peaks and nadirs in the data but sometimes the algorithms fail to identify peaks and nadirs. Please check the following figure, as you can see after peak 11 it failed to select peak:

[image]

I want to write a code in which:

- I can select a peak/nadir point on the graph and save it in the vector
- update the indexes.

Here is part of the code: In the first part I tried to mark the peaks and nadirs and find the maximum amplitude

```
mn_ln=min(size(peaks,2), size(nadirs,2));

amp=zeros(1,mn_ln);
fig=figure(10),  hold on, plot(y,'r') , 
plot(peaks,y(peaks),'ro');plot(nadirs,y(nadirs),'bo'); 


 for i=1:length(amp)-1  
      text( peaks(i)+0.3, y(peaks(i)) , sprintf(num2str(i)))
      text( nadirs(i)+0.3, y(nadirs(i)) , sprintf(num2str(i)))

     if    y(nadirs(i))>y(nadirs(i+1))
           amp(i)=abs(y(peaks(i))-y(nadirs(i+1)));
           line([peaks(i),peaks(i)],[y(peaks(i)),y(nadirs(i+1))],'Color','k','LineWidth',2)


     else y(nadirs(i))<=y(nadirs(i+1))
          amp(i)=abs(y(peaks(i))-y(nadirs(i)));
           line([peaks(i),peaks(i)],[y(peaks(i)),y(nadirs(i))],'Color','k','LineWidth',2)
     end     

 end
    dcm_obj = datacursormode(fig); set(dcm_obj,'DisplayStyle','datatip','SnapToDataVertex','off','Enable','on')
 c_info = getCursorInfo(dcm_obj)
 peaks(i), y(peaks(i)=c_info.Position
```

I am new to Matlab, I am sorry in advance if my question seems too easy. But I could not add coordinates of new points to the vector and update all the indexes. My goal is to add a peak in the local maxima (peaks 12, between nadirs 12 and 13 and update all the indexes (make the next peaks 13,..and so on).
Thanks and I appreciate your help

Comment: Can you provide any code, please?

Comment: yes, sure..I will add it to the question

Comment: It's possible an XY problem...sigh. I would suggest you google more about basic peak analysis and read them all. There are already many solutions on Mathworks' fileexchange database if you don't have `Signal Processing Toolbox`. I think a better way to do is studying them rather than re-inventing your own one.

Answer (score 0):

So in short, your algorithm is not perfect so you want to override by manually select a peak when it misses?

It's not too difficult to implement a callback function that clicks on a graph and add a new line. Well, although I would think it's better to review your algorithm, that's not my concern though. Just thought you might be missing the bigger picture here.

`ginput` can do what you want. I will provide an example here so you know how it could work on your project.

#### The following example add a line to sin wave plot after clicking anywhere on the figure window.

First, create a function called `capLine`. You would have to do it in a separate file unless you are using R2016b or later, which has **function in script** support.

```
function capLine(fig,eventData,style)
    [x y] = ginput(1);
    yLim = get(fig,'ylim');    
    line([x x],ylim,'lineStyle',style,'color','r');
end
```

Then connect `capLink` to the `ButtonDownFcn` callback.

```
p = plot(0:0.01:10,sin(0:0.01:10));
set(gca,'ButtonDownFcn',@(fig,eventData)capLink(fig,eventData,'--'))
```

The demo may not be exactly what you can directly implement. But it at least gives you an idea of how it could work.